# Trait template class for checking if a class has a member with specific name

Tags: c++, class, templates, traits, c++98

I made this code for checking if a class has a member called first:

```
template <class T>
struct ClassA{
    T first;
};

template <class T>
struct ClassB{
    T second;
};

template <class T>
struct has_member_named_first
{
    typedef char valid_type;
    typedef struct { char array[2]; } not_valid_type;

    template <typename U>
    static valid_type __test(typename U::first*);

    template <typename U>
    static not_valid_type __test(...);

    static const bool value = sizeof(__test<T>(0)) == sizeof(valid_type);
};
```

By defining **`valid_type`** as char and **`not_valid_type`** as struct { char array[2]; } we can make the last line **`sizeof(__test<T>(0)) == sizeof(valid_type);`** return true or false based on the instantiated function __test and thus determine if a class has a member named **`first`**.

```
int main()
{
   std::cout << has_type_named_first<ClassA<int> >::value << std::endl;
   std::cout << has_type_named_first<ClassB<int> >::value << std::endl;
   return (0);
}
```

but i got in the output:

> 0
>
> 0

Comment: You are looking for `typename U::first`, but  `first` is not a type.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `static yes_type check(decltype(U::first)*);`, if that compiles with C++98.

Comment: ok that is true but my intention here is i want to check if a member is named first, this member shouldn't be a type

Comment: ok it's compiled with c++98

Comment: but what confused me is that `decltype` is not a keyword of c++98. still it's compiled with c++98 but the result is the same.

Comment: i use `decltype(&U::first)` and it's work.

Comment: `decltype(&U::first)` will also detect a member function named `first()`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++98, checks for if an expression is valid using SFINAE can be done like this:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct has_member_named_first
{
private:
    typedef char valid_type;
    typedef char(&not_valid_type)[2];

    template<std::size_t> struct check_expr;

    template <typename U>
    static valid_type test(check_expr<sizeof((void) (YOUR_EXPRESSION_HERE), 0)>*);

    template <typename U>
    static not_valid_type test(...);

public:
    static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(valid_type);
};
```

To check for a data member, you can have `YOUR_EXPRESSION_HERE` be `static_cast<U*>(0)->first` or simply `U::first`.

To check for a member function or data member, use `&U::first`.